# Primefaces tieredMenu, Chrome only bug - The subitems disconnects from the menu

Tags: primefaces

The sub items overlay panel disconnects from the main menu with a small gap and when try to hover it closes making impossible to select an item.
It is not reproducible always. We found it while increasing and decreasing screen resolution. I can't say it happens in a specific resolution.

Primefaces 6.2
Chrome version: 79.0.3945.130

```
    <p:commandButton value="Manage Menu" id="managePrjMenu"/>   
        <p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="managePrjMenu" my="left top" 
                      at="left bottom" style="width:auto;>
             <p:submenu label="SubMenu1">
                <p:menuitem url="url1" value="subMenuItem1"/>
             </p:submenu>
             <p:menuitem url="url2" value="menuItem1"/>
        </p:tieredMenu>
```

Comment: 1: Can you post screenshots, this code does not really help. 2: What is 'Changing screen resolution'?  Is it zooming (ctrl-+/-) or real resolution changes. 3: Cannot reproduce in the showcase with Chrome 80. 4: Tried PF 8?

Comment: And do you have a specific theme or CSS (the above is not a [mcve])

Comment: @Kukeltje : Thanks for responding. No specific theme. 1. I don't have the screenshot. Will see if I can get it. 2. Correct, Crtl+/-; 3. Will try from showcase. I just want to make sure if anyone has experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause, it's the CSS padding on the sub menu dialog. Setting the padding to 0 fixed the issue.